# How to start the metasploit service in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, services, metasploit

I wanted to start the metasploit service to start armitage. But when i am typing in my console the command:

```
sudo service metasploit start
```

It says:

```
Failed to start metasploit.service: Unit metasploit.service not found.
```

I installed metasploit. It is connected to postgresql, so the question is how can I start or install this service?

Answer (score 0):

It says there is no service called metasploit, You can find the service script in `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/systemd/system` or `/usr/lib/systemd`
Also i think there should be some useful things in config file.

Comment: I couldn't find this service. What now?